# lambda constness?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, constants, c++11

c++0x supports lambdas that capture values by reference:

```
[&] -> ret_t { return 0; }
```

Does it make sense to capture const references?

```
[const &] -> ret_t { return 0; }
```

More fundamentally to the question at hand; **is there a way to detect if a given lambda being passed as a `std::function<>` is free of side-effects?**

Comment: *"Does it make sense to capture const references?"* -- Not much no.  Captured values are not like parameters, the function knows exactly what objects it's getting, i.e. they're not variable.  And there's no problem with capturing const objects with &, they'll still be const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't even guarantee that what's in a `std::function` **is** a lambda or not. You certainly can't guarantee that it has no side effects.

If you want to ensure that the lambda function you write doesn't have side effects (to the extent that such things can be ensured), the only way to do that is to capture nothing: `[]`.

Comment: if i am the one writing the function being passed, i can "make sure" it doesn't have side effects, but if i am the one writing a library that expects a function callback without side-effects, i don't have any way to know what kind of constness the function i'm being passed has, is this what you are saying?

Comment: @lurscher: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: capture nothing doesn't really help, as the lambda might modify a global or static var

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Obviously. C++ is not a functional language. Any function could theoretically modify any global or static. The question is therefore one of minimizing the potential scope of modifications.